# Applying custom nginx.conf in GAE flex/custom for django API

Tags: django, google-app-engine, nginx, dockerfile

I am trying to run django on a custom runtime of nginx so that I can interact with the nginx.conf file. SSH-ing into the deployed instance with the below files reveals that the folders I create for nginx are not created on app engine. Is there another way I should be doing this in order to customize nginx for deploying django on app engine? I am able to deploy the django API succesfully, but I want the nginx routing for my tenantsbehing routed from my Angular front end.

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7 AS build-stage
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PORT 8080
ENV DATABASE_URL postgres://$CREDS
RUN mkdir /sd
WORKDIR /sd
ADD requirements.txt postgres_credential.json ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /sd/

FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/app_engine

# Create a simple file to handle heath checks. Health checking can be disabled
# in app.yaml, but is highly recommended. Google App Engine will send an HTTP
# request to /_ah/health and any 2xx or 404 response is considered healthy.
# Because 404 responses are considered healthy, this could actually be left
# out as nginx will return 404 if the file isn't found. However, it is better
# to be explicit.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah && \
    echo "healthy" > /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah/health

# Finally, all static assets.
ADD template/ /usr/share/nginx/template/
RUN chmod -R a+r /usr/share/nginx/template

#CMD python3 ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

bash commands on GAE instance

```
alex@aef-back /usr/share $ cd /var/nginx
-bash: cd: /var/nginx: No such file or directory
alex@aef-back /usr/share $ cd /etc/nginx
-bash: cd: /etc/nginx: No such file or directory
alex@aef-back /usr/share $ cd /var/log/app_engine/
alex@aef-back /var/log/app_engine $ pwd
/var/log/app_engine
alex@aef-back /var/log/app_engine $ ls
app  health_check  health_check.202012050634_0.log
alex@aef-back /var/log/app_engine $ cd /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah
-bash: cd: /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah: No such file or directory
alexmacdon94@aef-back-20201204t072728-9236 /var/log/app_engine $
```

nginx-custom.conf

```
server_name _;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        }
```

cloud build log

```
Step #1: Step 11/16 : RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
Step #1:  ---> Running in c48758488e52
Step #1: Removing intermediate container c48758488e52
Step #1:  ---> d5b17f9f8874
Step #1: Step 12/16 : COPY nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
Step #1:  ---> 22fbfb3ddfda
Step #1: Step 13/16 : RUN mkdir -p /var/log/app_engine
Step #1:  ---> Running in 695f94769a04
Step #1: Removing intermediate container 695f94769a04
Step #1:  ---> 9ed88f52cf17
Step #1: Step 14/16 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah &&     echo "healthy" > /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah/health
Step #1:  ---> Running in 5b8e2448d194
Step #1: Removing intermediate container 5b8e2448d194
Step #1:  ---> 73a48dccb523
Step #1: Step 15/16 : ADD template/ /usr/share/nginx/template/
Step #1:  ---> 8be309b7b146
Step #1: Step 16/16 : RUN chmod -R a+r /usr/share/nginx/template
Step #1:  ---> Running in 2f4f07a124ee
Step #1: Removing intermediate container 2f4f07a124ee
Step #1:  ---> 364d25299630
Step #1: Successfully built 364d25299630
```

app.yaml

```
env: flex
runtime: custom
#entrypoint: python3 ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
#entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$8080 sd.wsgi.dev
service: back


handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: .*
  script: sd.wsgi.dev
  #secure: always
```

Comment: Just taking a guess - maybe you need to pass the entire desired filepath to `COPY`? As in, `COPY nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-custom.conf`

Comment: Thanks, but the problem persists - that folder still isn't there

Comment: I have tried the solution here: but the /usr/share/nginx folder doesn't get created either

Comment: It's weird that the `/etc/nginx` directory doesn't exist, I would assume it would because you're using the nginx image. Perhaps you have to mkdir first? Have you looked through the docs for the COPY command? They might be useful: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Comment: I will try making the directory as well, but removing the 2 run and copy commands after nginx in the dockerfile does cause the entire site to give a 502 error - so it seems that those commands are doing something.

Comment: I tried adding a mkdir directory below 'from nginx' but it gives this. Seems like the folder exists Step #1: Step 11/18 : RUN mkdir ./etc/nginx
Step #1:  ---> Running in 2d14bb7482fe
Step #1: mkdir: cannot create directory './etc/nginx': File exists
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir ./etc/nginx' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
Step #1:

Comment: If the directory already exists as your error message indicates, it may be that it was created but not granted proper permissions, try doing the mkdir with the `–m777` flag to give permissions to everyone, as a test.